# How to debug code that uses boost w/o losing sanity?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, debugging

Boost is a great set of libraries and it really *boosts* productivity. But debugging code that uses it is a total nightmare. Sure, stepping through twenty thousand header files can be a valuable intellectual exercise, but what if you need to do it over and over again?

Is there a developer-friendly way of just skipping the boost portion and having the debugger go straight to my code?

Visual Studio has a [DebuggerStepThroughAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx) for .NET framework. Is there anything similar for native C++?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can skip the boost namespace entirely by using the techniques described [here](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2006/07/advanced_visual_1.html). Just use something like:

`boost\:\:.*=NoStepInto`

... in the relevant registry entry.

However if your code gets called from within boost (e.g. through a `boost::function` or similar) then your code will be skipped as well! I'll be interested if someone can come up with a good solution for *that* problem...

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the called function? Most debuggers I've worked with will get that one, although I've never explicitly disabled stepping into a namespace before :)

Comment: Andreas: heh, yeah that's happened to me before. You have to be quick around here!
workmad3: Yep, although if you don't know what the boost::function is currently assigned to, you can't really set a breakpoint...

Answer (score 11):

There's no platform/compiler independent way, but I've been told that you can tell the debugger to not "step into" certain functions or classes. You should look up the registry key: `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\NativeDE\StepOver]` and create a string value named as a number in the order the rules should apply (I'm a bit confused about it too, but I guess that the rules are simply ordered in the (possibly reverse) way they should be applied) and set it to something like: "boost::.*=NoStepInto". E.g.:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\NativeDE\StepOver]
"10"="boost\:\:.*=NoStepInto"
```

You can read a little bit more [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/andypennell/archive/2004/02/06/69004.aspx).