# Is it possible to get the debugger to display the name of the function pointed to by a boost function object?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, boost-bind

When debugging code using boost function and bind in Visual Studio, I would like to be able to have the debugger show information about the actual function pointed to by the boost functor. For instance the name of the function, the signature of the original function (before bind was used on it), or the state of the functor.

At the moment I have to step through the code to find out which function it is, and that requires stepping all the way through the boost code first.

Does anyone know if this has been done or even if it can be done?

Thank you!

**Edit** I'd also be very happy to find out that someone has developed an answer to this question by now: [How to debug code that uses boost w/o losing sanity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298024/how-to-debug-code-that-uses-boost-w-o-losing-sanity)

(I mean the problem mentioned in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298024/how-to-debug-code-that-uses-boost-w-o-losing-sanity/298038#298038): How to step over the boost code but still step into the code called by the boost::function...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an initiative in boost to make [debug visualizers](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/DebuggerVisualizers). There are already debug visualizers for different types (variant, multi_index, shared_ptr and more).

Unfortunately boost::function is not there, but you can write a visualizer yourself as described there (and maybe submit it to boost ;). Alternatively you can make a request to write one for you.

Regards,
Ovanes

Answer (score 0):

Using visual studio and it's Debug Visualizer, as pointed to by ovanes, it is possible to get the pointed to function when hovering over the variable.

As I don't want to spam this post full of it, I only provide here the first 12 function types. If you really need more you will likely be able to extend it. I sent similar code to a boost doc developer and eventually it will get published there as well.

Currently, this visualizer type will display more or less garbage, when nothing is actually bound to an function object. And please note that this is somewhat an early draft.

```
boost::function0<*> { preview( #("func=", $e.functor.bound_memfunc_ptr.memfunc_ptr) ) }
boost::function1<*,*> { preview( #("func=", $e.functor.bound_memfunc_ptr.memfunc_ptr) ) }
boost::function2<*,*,*> { preview( #("func=", $e.functor.bound_memfunc_ptr.memfunc_ptr) ) }
boost::function3<*,*,*,*> { preview( #("func=", $e.functor.bound_memfunc_ptr.memfunc_ptr) ) }
boost::function4<*,*,*,*,*> { preview( #("func=", $e.functor.bound_memfunc_ptr.memfunc_ptr) ) }
boost::function5<*,*,*,*,*,*> { preview( #("func=", $e.functor.bound_memfunc_ptr.memfunc_ptr) ) }
boost::function6<*,*,*,*,*,*,*> { preview( #("func=", $e.functor.bound_memfunc_ptr.memfunc_ptr) ) }
boost::function7<*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*> { preview( #("func=", $e.functor.bound_memfunc_ptr.memfunc_ptr) ) }
boost::function8<*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*> { preview( #("func=", $e.functor.bound_memfunc_ptr.memfunc_ptr) ) }
boost::function9<*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*> { preview( #("func=", $e.functor.bound_memfunc_ptr.memfunc_ptr) ) }
boost::function10<*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*> { preview( #("func=", $e.functor.bound_memfunc_ptr.memfunc_ptr) ) }
boost::function11<*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*> { preview( #("func=", $e.functor.bound_memfunc_ptr.memfunc_ptr) ) }
boost::function12<*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*> { preview( #("func=", $e.functor.bound_memfunc_ptr.memfunc_ptr) ) }
```