# How do I configure Visual Studio to 'skip' smart pointer code when debugging?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I know that it's possible to configure VS to not step through particular functions (e.g. boring smart pointer code that you know works and just gets in the way of understanding the code while debugging). How do I do this for the custom smart pointer used in the code I'm debugging?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug code that uses boost w/o losing sanity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298024/how-to-debug-code-that-uses-boost-w-o-losing-sanity)

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626744/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-avoiding-stepping-into-certain-functions-in-visua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/visual-studio-msvc-debugging-NoStepInto.html

> Visual Studio 9 (2010)
>   Visual Studio 2010 introduced a few small changes--in particular, you should simply leave out "=NoStepInto" when you want to avoid stepping into a function:
>
> 10 string\:\:.*
>
> Using "=NoStepInto" will simply not work. Secondly, you can now put your configuration in HKCU, rather than HKLM, allowing you to keep your settings from interfering with other users, but writing to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\NativeDE\StepOver.
>
> Lastly, I've heard reports that the old syntax using \oper no longer works. A simple workaround is to use:
>
> .*operator.*
>
> (Note the ommision of =NoStepInto as well.)